# Looping through file printing lines matching pattern

Tags: java

I am reading a file and wanting to only print lines that start with a space and all of the other lines I want to print out "hi". This is what I have now.

```
while((first = frBr.readLine()) != null) {

         if(first.startsWith(" ")) {
             System.out.println(first);
         }
         else if((!(first.startsWith(" "))){
                System.out.println("Hi");

         } 
}
```

Comment: you can replace else if((! with just else{ it does the same thing, make it less readable, and what was your question? Please update your question with proper request

Comment: Other than the fact that you're testing the same condition twice (the `else` already does this), do you have a problem here?

Comment: If the first condition is false, you can assume the second will be true and not repeat the test.

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an additional test for the else clause.

```
while ((first = frBr.readLine()) != null) {
    if (first.startsWith(" ")) {
        System.out.println(first);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    } 
 }
```

Note that it is possible that a line start with characters like **tab** (`\t`) that seems spaces but that are not spaces. In this case you print Hi and not the line.

If you need to print the line for any white char you can use the method [`isWhiteSpace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(char)) of `Character`:

> Determines if the specified character is white space according to Java

Here is the code using it.

```
while ((first = frBr.readLine()) != null) {
    // Check also if first has at least one character
    if (Character.isWhiteSpace(first.charAt(0)) {
        System.out.println(first);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Hi");
    } 
 }
```